# CakePHP find with 2 HABTM relationships

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm working on project that run on CakePHP 2 framework. In this application I have:

models:

```
Wallnote, User, Group
```

relationships:

```
Group HABTM User
Wallnote HABTM User
Wallnote HABTM Group
```

tables:

```
wallnotes

 - id
 - user_id (owner id)
 - ...

users_wallnotes

 - user_id
 - wallnote_id

groups_wallnotes

 - group_id
 - wallnote_id

groups_users

 - group_id
 - user_id
```

I'm using the relationships "Wallnote HABTM User" and "Wallnote HABTM Group" as a filter i.e. user_id/group_id(6) wallnote_id(10) mean, that wallnote with id 10 will be visible for user with id 6, respectively for all users in group with id 6.

I would like to find all wallnotes matching these conditions:

1. logged user is an owner of this wallnote OR
2. wallnote was shared with logged user -> record in table users_wallnotes OR
3. wallnote was shared with some group and logged user is member of this group

It is possible to do this using find() function?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two roles: group and user.
it's very difficult to handle it with User and Group separately...
I think the standard way is you have unique role for each user and group, for handling this you must have this tables:

```
wallnotes
 - id
 - user_id (owner id)
 - ...

roles
 - id
 - user_id
 - group_id
(each rows in this table have group_id or user_id , no both of them)

roles_wallnotes
 - id
 - role_id
 - wallnote_id
```

when you create a user(or group) you must create a role for it. So all groups and users, now have unique id.

for example you have 2 groups(with 1,2 ids) and 4 users(with 1,2,3,4 ids), then:

```
users :
|id|name |
---|------
1  | user1
2  | user2
3  | user3
4  | user4

groups :

|id|name |
---|------
1  | group1
2  | group2

roles :
|id| user_id | group_id |
---|---------|----------|
1  |   1     |  null    | 
2  |   2     |  null    |
3  |   3     |  null    |
4  |   4     |  null    |
5  |  null   |   1      |
6  |  null   |   2      |
```

now you must have this relations:

```
Role hasOne Group
Role hasOne User
Wallnote HABTM Role
```

with this solution you can easily use find function for retrieve your data you need...